# swift - Using Delegate Method's Return Value to Set Variable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

To give you a basic idea of what I want to accomplish, I would like to have a map that zooms in to the user's current location and then follows the user at that zoom level.

In view_did_load I have:

```
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.075, 0.075)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLat, longitude: currentLong), span: span)
    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

Below that I have a delegate function for my location manager:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) -> (lat: CLLocationDegrees, long: CLLocationDegrees) {
    let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0]
    let currentLong = userLocation.coordinate.longitude
    let currentLat = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
    return (currentLat, currentLong)
}
```

Is it possible to use the return value from this delegate method to set the latitude and longitude where I declare my region variable? Currently when I try this it says "Constant 'currentLat' used before being initialized" and "Constant 'currentLong' used before being initialized." My approach might be completely different from the solution, but thank you for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; if you change the type of the function by adding a return the LocationManager will not call the altered function, much less use its return value.  If the method signatures do not exactly match your function does not implement the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol, no matter what its name is.

Instead you should simply update your MapView inside the didUpdateLocations function, if this is part of your viewController, or, if you have a singleton that wraps CoreLocationManager, post a notification and have your map ViewController listen for the notification and update your mapView when the notification is received.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot! I changed my didUpdateLocations function to update the map itself. However, when I put the above code from my viewDidLoad in this function, it says "ambiguous reference to member 'map'".

Comment: After messing around for a while, I ended up creating a new, different function solely to change the value for my "region" variable. To accomplish this, I had to make "region" a global variable. My code now works when testing it on a device, but not on the simulator (as a heads up to anyone who reads this in the future).